# Ajax request with ionic to local server

Tags: ionic-framework

i'm new to ionic and ajax.
I have a local restful server that returns json outputs and it works normally with the browser.Then, with ionic i'm trying to get the same response in order to handle that output.
The problem is that the server returns nothing, even with the command "ionic serve". The error function runs instead the success one.
Can someone help me?

This is the script used to make the ajax request

```
var rootURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/conv1";
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL+'/relat/view',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $('#divTrip').append('<ul>');

            $.each(data, function(i, rows){
                $('#divTrip').append('<li >'+rows.nome+ ' '+rows.cognome+'<br></li><br>');

            });

            $('#divTrip').append('</ul>');

            alert(data[0].cognome);         
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert('Error: '+e); 
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: can you post your error? ... is it a CORS error?

Comment: Hi, the alert just reports Error: [Object object]

Comment: mm try to don't alert it ..but log in console..ù

Comment: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead[Ulteriori informazioni]  jquery.min.js:1
Bloccata richiesta multiorigine (cross-origin): il criterio di corrispondenza dell’origine non consente la lettura della risorsa remota da http://192.168.56.1:8080/convegno1/relatori/view. Motivo: header CORS “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” mancante.